# How to parse a json object value with no key in a json array in android?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

how can i parse the json array below, my target is to pass the object that has no value?

I have tried returning the json object using their keys but my problem is how to display the json that has no key in a textview?

```
[
[
    "Why are teachers being paid poorly?",
    {
        "answer": "minimum wage is 30,000",
        "candidate": "Nnamdi kalu"
    },
    "what is the minimum wage for teachers?",
    {
        "answer": "net worth is $200,000",
        "candidate": "Nnamdi kalu"
    },
    {
        "answer": "Teachers minimum wage is $200,000",
        "candidate": "Nnamdi kalu"
    },
    "What can you do to improve the Agriculture section?",
    "why do you delay in salary payment and how do you intend to solve late payment of salary?",
    "Checking if i can ask you more questions, can i ?",
    "What can you do to improve the football game?",
    "what is your name",
    "what are your agenda",
    "What can you do to help young entrepreneurs?"
 ]
]
```

Am expecting to display the datas in a form of a quiz app?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have a `JSONArray` with multiple possible types of values. Each element in the array could be either a `String` or a `JSONObject`.

You can use the `JSONArray.get()` method to get each element, and then use the `instanceof` operator to check whether the element is a `String` or a `JSONObject`.

Let's imagine that your posted example is stored in a `JSONArray` called `array`. You could write this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    Object o = array.get(i);
    if (o instanceof JSONObject) {
        System.out.println("object");
    } else if (o instanceof String) {
        System.out.println("string");
    }
}
```

You'd get this output:

> ```
> string
> object
> string
> object
> object
> string
> ...
> ```

Now you can replace my `System.out.println()` calls with real code, and you should be on your way.